# Home/Small office server - Ubuntu(wireless??)

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, home-server, ubuntu-server

Would a wireless home/small office server be practical? My idea is to use an Ubuntu server and it will function as a simple file storage system.

On the other hand there is the possibility of media storage(later down the line) which means streaming videos to a users computer/device.

Is wireless a practical solution for both of these uses? Or would there be too much of delay/inconsistancy when moving/streaming media. Does anyone have any experience with wireless servers or would the regular wired setup far outweigh the wireless idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stream media over WIFI, you'll at least want a WIFI-N network card into it... But if you want to stream some 1080P HD movie, you'll be better with a wired 1 gbps network connexion.

WIFI is great, but not always on heavy usage base...

Comment: (WIFI-N is what I was going to go with.) So to be able to do it all basically wireless is not the way to go, if you wanna keep up with the times?

Comment: You got it. Wireless is not the best way to go for what you want to achieve here.